# Multispectral orthomosaic appears as grainy mass of pixels in QGIS

Tags: qgis, agisoft-photoscan

After creating a multispec orthomosaic of an agricultural field using Agisoft, I exported the mosaic as a .tif and attempted to view it within QGIS before performing downstream analysis (mainly extraction of vegetation indices). However, the appearance of the mosaic in QGIS is somewhat alarming. Is anyone aware of the settings in QGIS I may be missing, or do you suspect there is an issue with my export settings in Agisoft? I have included screenshots of the normal-appearing mosaic in Agisoft, the problematic view in QGIS, and the export settings used in Agisoft.

[image: QGIS]
[image: Agisoft]
[image: Export Settings]

In case the embedded images aren't loading properly:
https://ibb.co/vmHzGMN
https://ibb.co/bB2zWQ8
https://ibb.co/7zjXg3H

Comment: What bands does the multispectral image contain? Which ones are being used to stylize the image in QGIS?

Comment: @Micha The bands contained in the mosaic are blue, green, red, red edge, and near infrared (the drone used was a DJI Phantom 4 Multispectral RTK). Currently QGIS is labeling the bands "Band 1," Band 2," and "Band 3," though it doesn't provide identities for each band. I can post a screenshot of this on Monday when I return to the office if that would be useful for you!

Comment: So when you **stylize** the raster in QGIS, be sure to allocate band 3 to red, band 2 to green and band 1 to blue. (or band 5 to red if you'd like to see a "false color" image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple: by deselecting the "Write alpha channel" option, the 5-band orthomosaic displayed normally when viewed in QGIS. The alpha channel is intended to be used to store additional information and does not need to be written during file export in this case. More can be found about alpha channels in TIFFs at this [link](https://www.graphicsmill.com/docs/gm/working-with-tiff-extra-channels.htm).